# AOP: Custom Model Binder Attribute using Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, aop, ninject

In short: I am trying to create a custom model binder that will take in the type of user and get their id, then use a service class to retrieve the strongly typed object.

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Elabaration:

I have ninject setup with all my bindings within my DomainService layer, 3 web ui's are hooked up to the domain service layer. Each asp.net mvc app loads the bindings into the kernal.

//my custom model binder

```
public class UserModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private IAuthenticationService auth;

        public UserModelBinder(IAuthenticationService _auth, EntityName type, 
        string loggedonuserid)
        {
            this.auth = _auth;
            CurrentUserType = type;
            CurrentUserId = loggedonuserid;
        }


        public EntityName CurrentUserType { get; private set; }
        private string CurrentUserId {  get; set; }

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            object loggedonuser = null;

            if (CurrentUserType == EntityName.Client)
                loggedonuser = GetLoggedOnClientUser(CurrentUserId);
            else if (CurrentUserType == EntityName.Shop)
                loggedonuser = GetLoggedOnShopUser(CurrentUserId);
            else
                throw new NotImplementedException();

            return loggedonuser;
        }

        public ClientUser GetLoggedOnClientUser(string loggedonuserid)
        {
            var user = _auth.GetLoggedOnClientUser(loggedonuserid);
            if (user == null)
                throw new NoAccessException();

            return user;
        }

        public ShopUser GetLoggedOnShopUser(string loggedonuserid)
        {
            var user = _auth.GetLoggedOnShopUser(loggedonuserid);
            if (user == null)
                throw new NoAccessException();

            return user;
        }

    }
```

my Global.aspx.cs

```
// using NInject to override application started
        protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            // hand over control to NInject to register all controllers
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);



 //how do I instantiate?
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(object), new 
            UserModelBinder(null,EntityName.Client, User.Identity.Name));

        }
```

My problem is IAuthentication is a service, it is connected to other things like a repository, how do I actually instantiate this properly? Should I create a new NinjectModule? I am really confused with this so any help is greatly appreciated. I have tried to pass in Container.Get(); - but it is null...

NOTE: the reason why I am creating a modelbinder- all controllers will require the type of user as I my service layer requires which type of user is making a request, most methods in my service layer will have overloads where it will do one thing for a ShopUser or ClientUser or any other user in the system...

**EDIT**:
I could very easiy within my controller call upon the IAuthenticationService and get the type of user and pass into my domainservice layer to process the relevant tasks but I just want to know how it is possible with the ModelBindings (and if it makes sense to do it that way).

Edit2: Is there a working sample of using a custom Attribute with AOP with the custom attribute calling/binding/getting an instance of ISomethingService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Service Locator pattern here. Pass the Ninject Container (IKernel?) to the constructor and resolve the AuthenticationService each time you need to bind something.

A refinement of this could be to have a constructor argument Func where you pass the function to resolve the service. This would be more explicit and removes the dependency on Ninject. Something like this:

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    Func<IAuthenticationService> _resolveAuthService;

    public MyModelBinder(Func<IAuthenticationService> resolveAuthService)
    {
         _resolveAuthService = resolveAuthService;
    }

    public override object Bind(Context c)
    {
        var authService = _resolveAuthService();

        authService.GetSomething();

        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: @rmac: The service locator pattern looks good, however an AOP approach might be better... I am changing the title of my post to slightly amend, sorry!

Comment: Did you remove the constraint of MVC version 2 as well? MVC 3 has much better support for injection and I believe there are ways to have it resolve a new model binder instance each request. That would be the optimal solution.

Comment: I have a hard time picturing what it is you want to do with AOP. You need to elaborate a bit there I think.

Comment: no i removed asp.net mvc2 but I left the tag on for asp.net 3.5- which basically rules out .net 4 runtime, I am going to change the asp.net mvc to asp.net mvc2 to avoid any conflicts... sorry! I know asp.net mvc3 has IModelBinderProvider which would work fantastically well for the scenario above, but I dont have that option with asp.net2...

Comment: @rcmac how would I instantiate or register this class inside the Global.asax? ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new MyModelBinder(???));

Comment: I actually figured out what this was all about- what you said was right however for simplicity I chose to [Inject] or use the Container directly to get what I needed, I am hard coding to a DI but it is all good...